# IPTables "iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)"

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I'm trying to get iptables working for my embedded Debian system, kernel version 2.6.35.3-571-gcca29a0.

I've tried to enable iptables support in the kernel by selecting these options (this is a diff between the new config and the deault config for the board), see pastebin.com/ipxycuGR

After booting the board I try to run "iptables -L -n" I get this:

```
root@ts7600-47aad3:~# iptables -L -n
FATAL: Module ip_tables not found.
iptables v1.4.14: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

My list of modules installed is this:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
x_tables               11384  0
ppp_deflate             3528  0
ppp_async               6686  1
crc_ccitt               1045  1 ppp_async
ppp_generic            18035  6 ppp_async,ppp_deflate
slhc                    4425  1 ppp_generic
binfmt_misc             6401  1
arcotg_udc             15990  0
ehci_hcd               36559  0
fsl_otg_arc            14084  0
usbcore               117957  2 fsl_otg_arc,ehci_hcd
```

How do I get iptables working?

Comment: something is wrong in your installation, you should have the ip_tables.ko module in the modules tree i.e. `find /lib/modules/\`uname -r\` -name ip_tables.ko`, if it's missing then try to reinstall your kernel i.e. `dpkg -l|grep 2.6.35; apt-get install linux-image-2.6.35...`